# customizing google maps in fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

The situation is that I am using Fragments to show 2 views in main activity, meaning that I have two tabs and in second tab I am showing a google map using below code

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                               Bundle savedInstanceState){

        RelativeLayout dashboardMapview = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_mapview, container, false);


        return dashboardMapview;
      }
    }
```

This is for second Tab, and I want to customize the map, for which I am using this code in above function.

imap = SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

```
    imap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

imap being a Google Map variable declared onCreate.

The problem is that getSupportFragmentManager is showing error. 
Also, I have used the same code for an activity having no tabs but only maps, and it works fine.

Mind that I am able to show google maps successfully on run, if I do't use above code for customization. The only problem is customization.

my dashboardMapview.xml looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

The xml also works fine if there are no tabs but a single activity.

I am using Google Maps API V2

And if it makes any sense, I think it is because I have inflated and returned a RelativeLayout, but the fragment is inside that.

Any ideas on how to customize a googlemap, which is being used on click of second tab in activity?

Comment: I guess you are you getting a nullpointer, right?

Comment: Well, actually eclipse is not letting me write that, I cannot compile the code. Eclipse gives some suggestions but none work

Comment: Please post post the errors then

Answer (score 0):

Found error, more of a silly mistake. Just had not extended FragmentActivity in mainactivity and getSupportFragmentManager() cannot be called without that.